# How to fix Devexpress Blazor update to 22.2.3 missing CSS?

Tags: css, blazor, devexpress

I have updated my Balzor webpage from 21.2.4 to 22.2.3 like this :

```
PM> Install-Package DevExpress.Blazor -Version 22.2.3
```

No problems so far. Followed the instruction [here](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1081253/the-location-of-css-resources-for-devexpress-blazor-controls-has-changed) and launched the webpage.

Problem : the `"_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs4.min.css"` do not exist when checking the Chrome devtool? I thought the `services.AddDevExpressBlazor(configure => configure.BootstrapVersion = BootstrapVersion.v4);` would have added it, but no?

Got this in the Head :

```
<link href="_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs4.min.css" asp-append-version="true" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap-external.bs4.min.css" asp-append-version="true" rel="stylesheet" />
```

How do I get the proper resources loaded?

Comment: Have you checked what is actually in _content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/ on the server ?

Comment: Have you called `services.AddDevExpressBlazor(configure => configure.BootstrapVersion = BootstrapVersion.v4);` in the `Startup.cs` file. ?

Comment: You may have to even clear the browser cache and rebuild the project.